# How should I hash this data in C#?

Tags: c#, security, hash

I have a string data field which is 12 characters, alphanumeric (letters and numbers). I need to perform a one-way hash on this field for security reasons. What algorithm should I use to avoid collisions (different values hashed to same value) for accurate reporting? Would this be do the trick?

```
Edit: Here is the code based on suggestions in comments so far:

public static string GetHashedValue(string Input)
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Input);
    bytes = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed().ComputeHash(bytes);
    String output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `SHA256Managed` is enough, you could also use the `SHA512Managed`.

Comment: Sufficient for what? Only you can tell us that, which makes this question off topic for here I'm afraid.

Comment: Sufficient to avoid collisions, as I stated @DavidG

Comment: Probably you should convert those bytes to a base64 string, not simply ASCII.Encoding which would cause loss of data and thus possible collision chance would be high.

Comment: What System.Text.Encoding value would be proper to avoid that if not ASCII @CetinBasoz? There are others like UTF8, UTF16, etc... My source data is all alphanumeric, though.

Here are the possible Encodings:

ASCII
UTF-16
UTF-32
UTF-7
UTF-8

Comment: I added as an answer, base64 encoding would prevent loss and you can get the bytes back as they are.

Comment: hashing is more than just obfuscation. It's _irreversible_, meaning once hashed _no one_ knows the original value any more.

Comment: SHA256 (or better SHA512) is *Sufficient to avoid collisions*, yes, but it is used for hashing, not obfuscation. Hashing and obfuscation are two different things. You cannot restore the original value from the hash.

Comment: I am sorry, I only know C# terms @CetinBasoz. Is one of these base 64?

ASCII
UTF-16
UTF-32
UTF-7
UTF-8

Comment: `BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty)` to get a hex string representation is probably fine as well.

Comment: Thank you for that information @RacilHilan. I do not need to restore the value, so I guess technically I need a hash, not just obfuscation. Though, technically, wouldn't all hashes also be obfuscations? Though not all obfuscations are hashes?

Comment: Sorry @JonathonChase.. what problem are you solving with that code?

Comment: base64 is also C# term (not C# only but in any programming language it is a well known term). Just look at my answer. BTW you confused people saying "obsfucation". It is a term used for different purpose (like code obsfucation).

Comment: Updated my title @CetinBasoz. I still need to know from this list, which would be appropriate:

ASCII
UTF-16
UTF-32
UTF-7
UTF-8

Comment: No hashing algorithm will **perfectly** avoid collisions. All you can hope for is to push the probability very low. If you **absolutely, positively, must** avoid collisions _at all costs_, you need to store the hash values and check against what you stored after every hash you generate, and then perhaps add a uniquifier in cases when the collision actually happens.

Comment: How about this code:

                public static string GetObfuscatedValue(string Input)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(Input);
                    bytes = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed().ComputeHash(bytes);
                    String output = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes);
                    return output;
                }

Comment: Why wouldn't you read my reply and use base64 :)

Comment: @CetinBasoz, Joel Coehoorn showed me where to use Base64 in his response.

Comment: Are storing a password or any type of sensitive data (SSN etc)?

Comment: *wouldn't all hashes also be obfuscations?* Well, not really. Obfuscation is  a process that makes something unclear. We usually use obfuscation to make it hard for others to reverse-engineer our applications and steal our efforts. Hashing on the other hand is a process that makes irreversible unique values for security purposes. One common thing we use hashing for is storing passwords (although using a key derivation function). If we over-simplify it, we can say that obfuscation is reversible (although hard), but hashing isn't. Also hashing produces unique output, but obfuscation doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you should get a base64 string to prevent loss of data, so you can avoid getting a high collision chance. ie:

```
public static string GetHashedValue(string Input)
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Input);
    bytes = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed().ComputeHash(bytes);
    string output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    return output;
}
```

EDIT: Hash is one way and is ideal for say storing passwords. If you want the original value back with a key then use a symmetric algorithm.

Comment: More than that, the `bytes` values are likely to contain a bunch of unprintable ascii characters. Base64 is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, yes by saying "loss" I meant that.

Comment: Ohhhh so THAT is where to use Base64.

So... Convert.ToBase64String(byte []) is better than System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(byte [])??? Cool!

Comment: @Infin8Loop, yes absolutely. Whenever you need to store some binary data as "string" (and then later convert back to bytes) use base64. All those ASCII, UTF8, ... encodings would cause loss of data  (as an example one of the bytes in the start might be hex 0x0 and you lose the rest of bytes unless you use base64).

Comment: How about this then for the super-duper final code?

                public static string GetHashedValue(string Input)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(Input);
                    bytes = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed().ComputeHash(bytes);
                    String output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    return output;
                }

Comment: @Infin8Loop, looks fine. I would prefer Unicode or UTF8 or ASCII but as longs as you are consistent that should be OK (Encoding is a complex topic - not sure if UTF8 is the most versatile and cross platform compatible one, above my head).

Comment: UTF8 Should be highly reliable.   If you absolutely need cross platform language agnostic and system agnostic encoding you should use UTF16.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, thanks for the info. I thought UTF8 might be better, as many other languages, running also on other platforms, seem to favor UTF8. I was wrong maybe.

Comment: Everyone *favors* UTF8 because it's backwards compatible with ascii and can potentially be smaller (probably more often than not in non-asian languages).  Honestly it should be fine in your case.  If you are curious, I would recommend reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not familiar with the concept of cryptographical hashes.

A crypto hash has a few properties, including (1) preimage-resistance, ie. you can't efficiently find the original value from a hash and (2) collision resistance, ie. you can't efficiently find a pair of inputs that have the same hash, and also given an input with a hash, you can't efficiently find another input with the same hash (weak and strong collision resistance).

However, this does not mean there are no collisions at all. There need to be inputs with the same hash value, because the output is of finite length (256 or 512 bits for sha256 and 512), but the inputs are finite but not bounded, ie. arbitrarily long. You can easily see that there are much more inputs than outputs, so there must be collisions.

It's just it's really hard to find them, which means that ideally in case of a crypto hash, the best method to find a collision is brute-force, which is infeasible for a 256bit output, let alone for 512.

So the answer to your question is that in case of sha256 or even sha512, it is really, *really* unlikely for you to ever find a collision *as long as there is no known attack against those algorithms*.

Now there are attacks against sha2, but realistically, it's still very unlikely for you to find a collision. See [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34256/sha256-security-what-does-it-mean-that-attacks-have-broken-46-of-the-60-rounds) for details.

For many purposes, sha2 is still good, for others, maybe not.

Note that contrary to another answer, one thing that sha2 is NOT good for is password hashing.

Comment: Can you explain why hashing is not good for password hashing?

Comment: Interestingly, because it's too fast. It's too easy to precompute and build rainbow tables - actually, there are already rainbow tables available so that you can try and break preimage resistance for many different types of input. For example.you can simply download a database of hashes for all strings with a maximum length of 9 characters, containing alphanumeric characters. Now that's pretty good for cracking a password. :)

Comment: Oh no, that is something about password being strong. Increase your character count and use any printables you can, also add a salt. Looks pretty safe to me. And not only that the attacked place might be throttling the trials. Otherwise, what do you suggest for passwords? A symmetric algorithm?

Comment: Not at all of course. The best practice is a key derivation function with many rounds, for example bcrypt or pbkdf2 with so many rounds that one hash computation takes about 0.2-0.3 seconds. That way, it won't be cracked. Salts with normal hashes won't help much, because computation is still fast and parallelly computable. Also you can't expect your users to remember 14+ character passwords.

Comment: Oh I see the confusion now. You are not saying "hashing" is not good for passwords, but saying that specifically for "SHA-2". Which contrary answer said sha2 was good? I thought you referred to my answer where I don't say anything about the algorithm chosen.

Comment: Well, I still think a hash in general is inadequate for storing a password. A key derivation function like pbkdf2 or bcrypt is not a simple hash, even if they are based on hashes. But maybe it's just a wording confusion betwern the two of us. :) I think saying hashes are ok for password storage is a bit misleading for the reasons detailed above.

Comment: I think the majority of the confusion is what is the goal.  If the goal is to create a unique *hash* that avoids collisions then a simple hash function is fine.  If the goal is to create a unique *hash* for security, ultimately you need a good secure hash, but the function in creating the hash (requiring a salt, and multiple rounds) is much more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid collisions is the problem of the century. But the solutions only depends of what is good enough for you.
If your input string is a password for a todo list application, then a Sha256 is sufficient, but if you need really strong security you should study your problem and tell us more about that.